# Modify/verifying build action of a particular file in project

Tags: msbuild

Using msbuild, is it possible to verify that the build action is content and not none?  A particular content file gets frequently modified, and for some reason when it is, the content type in the *.vbproj/*.csproj file sometimes get's switched to "None" from "Content".

Normally it looks like

```xml
 <Content Include="myfile.config">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
```

Sometimes it gets changed to:

```xml
 <None Include="myfile.config" />
```

And I'd like to make sure that is right, either by failing to build the project and forcing a manual change or by silently rewriting the value.

Is either possible?

Comment: Is the file in question actually the `app.config` file? There is special handling of the `app.config` file. It will always be copied to '<name>.[dll|exe].config'. Leave the `<None Include="app.config" />` line alone. However, if the file a .config and not the `app.config` file then, yes, you can check and error if the Item collection is not correct. (I'll post a fuller answer later.)

Comment: @JonathanDodds: It's not the app.config or web.config file, it's a totally separate file.

Answer (score 2):

It would be good to understand how and when the project is changed to include `myfile.config` in `None` instead of `Content`. But in the meantime, the build can report an error or silently fix the issue.

MSBuild supports [Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-properties?view=vs-2022) and [Items](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-items?view=vs-2022). A 'Property' is a single value and an 'Item' is a collection or set of values. The name 'Item' is a bit overloaded in the docs. For clarity I’ll use ‘Item Set’ for a set and ‘Item Value’ for an individual member of a set. [`Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/common-msbuild-project-items?view=vs-2022#content) and [`None`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/common-msbuild-project-items?view=vs-2022#none) are item sets.

MSBuild supports [batching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-batching?view=vs-2022) for item sets. Batching divides the item set into subsets based on matching metadata values. If the batch is on the `%(Identity)` metadata and each member of the item set has a unique value for `%(Identity)`, then the item set is divided into subsets where each subset has one member -- effectively equivalent to iterating the item set.

To test if `None` contains `myfile.config`:

```xml
    <PropertyGroup>
      <IsInNone>false</IsInNone>
      <IsInNone Condition="'myfile.config' == '%(None.Identity)'">true</IsInNone>
    </PropertyGroup>
```

The `$(IsInNone)` property could be used in an `Error` task.

To silently 'fix' the `myfile.config` there are a couple of considerations.

MSBuild has two phases: evaluation and execution. Essentially the evaluation phase looks at everything within the `Project` but not within a `Target`. All the 'top level' `PropertyGroup`s and `ItemGroup`s are defined and the execution order of `Target`s is determined. To ensure the silent fix is not done too early, it should be in a target.

An `Include` on an item set is additive. The `Include` can be with `KeepDuplicates="false"`, but item values with the same Identity and different metadata are not duplicates. To ensure there is only one `myfile.config` in `Content` the following code will `Remove` and then `Include` with the metadata.

```xml
  <Target Name="FixUp" BeforeTargets="BeforeBuild">
    <ItemGroup>
      <None Remove="myfile.config" />
      <Content Remove="myfile.config" />
      <Content Include="myfile.config">
        <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      </Content>
    </ItemGroup>
  </Target>
```

In the example I use `PreserveNewest` instead of `Always` for `CopyToOutputDirectory`. With `Always` a project will always be built regardless of whether the source and outputs are up to date because the copy must always be performed. If you need incremental builds to work, avoid `Always`.